# Deploying RichFaces 3.3.3 to Tomcat having MyFaces 2.2, PrimeFaces, OmniFaces etc

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, richfaces, jsf-2.2, myfaces

I have the following configuration ( don't get scared by the stack traces :) )

Tomcat 7.0.53 + All our jars - including MyFaces 2.2.3 / Omnifaces / PrimeFaces / etc...) are located apart of the web apps (not inside web-inf\lib , but inside the other path Tomcat\someName\lib... and are referenced from catalina.properties file with the common.loader)  this setup serves all our webapps just fine, except one legacy webapp that is using RichFaces 3.3.3 - RichFaces  jars are in that specific webapp lib folder, (which worked just fine while we were using MyFaces 2.0.11) but now after switching to the MyFaces 2.2.3 I'm getting the following exception

> **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/ComponentHandler**
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

...

> **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler**
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>           at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.loadClass(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:143)
>           ... 64 more

And it seems because of facelets packages changes between 2.0 and 2.2

So I tried dropping jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar to that webapp lib folder and got the following exception

> **javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot instantiate TagLibrary**
>           at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:424)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.FaceletsCompilerSupport.loadLibraries(FaceletsCompilerSupport.java:157)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.loadLibraries(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2520)

...

> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   **Caused by: java.lang.Exception: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.CoreLibrary must be an instance of org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.TagLibrary**
>           at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.createClass(TagLibraryConfig.java:542)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:419)
>           ... 50 more

So now I tried to drop the myfaces-impl-2.0.11 and myfaces-api-2.0.11 to that webapp lib folder , but now the webapp insn't even being deployed by Tomcat and throwing exception regarding OmniFaces (which is not even used by that webapp and not mentioned anywhere there)

> [2014-08-28 09:36:12,645 IDT] E 000001b4 (org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer#initFaces) An error occured while initializing MyFaces: **Class org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory is no
>   javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory**
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory is no javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
>           at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:320)
>           at javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:286)
>           at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:191)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configureApplication(FacesConfigurator.java:500)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:411)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:337)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:140)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:111)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I thought that it is possible to mix two different JSF versions (but I might be wrong) and maybe there is a better solution to make that Richfaces 3.3.3 work with JSF 2.2.3

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RichFaces 3.x is not compatible with JSF 2.2. Tomcat does not support isolated JSF class loading such as JBoss with `org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL` context param in `web.xml`, GlassFish with `<property name="useBundledJsf" value="true" />` in `glassfish-web.xml`, etc. So even when you supply another JSF version via the webapp, Tomcat keeps loading its own. This just can't work.

You've basically 3 options:

1. Deploy that RichFaces 3.x webapp on a separate Tomcat instance without those common libs.
2. Move those common libs from Tomcat back in those other webapps, so each webapp gets its own.
3. Upgrade to RichFaces 4.x. Been there, done that, they've a quite good [migration guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration).

Comment: Thanks, Gonna try third option: migrate to RichFaces 4  :'(

Comment: Option 4: Get rid of Richfaces :-)

Answer (score 0):

Following up in case anyone sees this while working on a migration from JSF 1.2. There's a chance you could be able to use your app on JSF 2.2. You likely won't benefit from any new 2.0 / 2.2 features, and it's better to move to RichFaces 4.0/4.5 if you plan to develop the application further. (Or move away from RichFaces as it's no longer developed).

At least I managed to deploy a RichFaces 3.3.4 application on JSF 2.2 (MyFaces) via Open Liberty.  Basically, we're making the app 2.0 compatible, and therefore able to run on 2.2.

You really should update the application, but, if you can't, I hope the following is useful.

1. Read over these two articles

- JSF 1.2 - 2.0 Migration: [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)

  - If using Facelets already, then should make the migration easier.
- RichFaces 3.3.3 and JSF 2.0: https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-14504

  - Good information. Also contains a section MyFaces specific integration problems.
  - Note the 3.3.3 has a security issue, so it's better to use 3.3.4.

2. Dependencies

- richfaces-api-3.3.4
- richfaces-ui-3.3.4
- richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.4 (make sure it's the jsf2 version)
- jsf-facelets-1.1.15  - key dependency for richfaces
- Any other dependencies required by those above.

3. Web.xml Config:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
    </context-param>
            
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

You'll need to setup the RichFaces Filter, too.

That should about do it or at least get you closer (depending on your app).