# com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.CoreLibrary must be an instance of org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.TagLibrary Error

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, myfaces, tomcat8

I am using  Myfaces 2.2.8 and Richfaces 4.5.x jar and tomcat 8. But when launch my url I am getting an error

"java.lang.Exception: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.CoreLibrary must be an instance of org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.TagLibrary"

My web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>jsfTomcat8</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>

 </welcome-file-list>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
<param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And Face-config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

My test.xhtml file

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-   transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<h:head/>
<body>
  Hello World!
    <h:outputText value="Calendar:" />
    <rich:calendar></rich:calendar>
</body>
 </ui:composition>
```

Stack-trace

```
   java.lang.Exception: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.CoreLibrary must be an instance of org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.TagLibrary
  org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.createClass(TagLibraryConfig.java:542)
 org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:419)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.FaceletsCompilerSupport.loadLibraries(FaceletsCompilerSupport.java:157)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.loadLibraries(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2526)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.createCompiler(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2172)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.initialize(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2464)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.<init>(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:309)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguageStrategy.<init>(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguageStrategy.java:52)
org.apache.myfaces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.initialize(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:104)
org.apache.myfaces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:73)
org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerImpl.java:183)
javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:133)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.checkResourceExists(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:569)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.handleSuffixMapping(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:507)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.calculateViewId(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:113)
org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.deriveLogicalViewId(ViewHandlerImpl.java:122)
javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.deriveLogicalViewId(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:112)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:225)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

anybody know possible reason for this error. thanks In advance

Comment: are you **sure** you are only using MyFaces? The stacktrace states otherwise. And please post full stacktraces

Comment: I am using myfaces-impl-2.2.8.jar and myfaces-api-2.2.8.jar , Edit question with stack trace

Comment: not by accident a facelets jar or something similar still in your project? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542335/deploying-richfaces-3-3-3-to-tomcat-having-myfaces-2-2-primefaces-omnifaces-et

Comment: I have tomahawk-1.1.10.jar .. Do u think this jar may cause problem for me??

Comment: is it a plain 1.1.10 or the tomahawk20-1.1.10? https://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html And btw, I use none of these... Just try googling a little

Comment: @ Kukeltje : thanks foe your suggestion....I was using tomhawk which compatible with  jsf -1......now It works -:) ....+1 for your suggestion