# jsf issue when trying to migrate from websphere 7 to websphere 9

Tags: jsf, websphere

Trying to migrate an application from WebSphere 7 to WebSphere 9 is causing this failure:

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.CoreLibrary must be an instance of org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.TagLibrary

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.CoreLibrary must be an instance of org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.TagLibrary
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.createClass(TagLibraryConfig.java:542)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:419)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.FaceletsCompilerSupport.loadLibraries(FaceletsCompilerSupport.java:157)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.loadLibraries(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2534)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.createCompiler(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2180)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.initialize(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2472)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.<init>(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:309)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguageStrategy.<init>(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguageStrategy.java:52)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.initialize(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:104)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerImpl.java:183)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:133)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:226)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: WebSphere 9 only provides the MyFaces JSF 2.2 implementation - this stack suggests there is an incompatibility with that spec version.  Are you using any component libraries in your application?  A similar tomahawk-related question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232554/com-sun-facelets-tag-jsf-core-corelibrary-must-be-an-instance-of-org-apache-myfa

Comment: Please leave the post as is, your own version is unreadable. This version is way better

Comment: I suspect you have a mixture of jsf implementations.